# Typescript equivalent of $.isEmptyObject({}) for empty object

Tags: jquery, typescript, is-empty

May I know what is the formal way of testing an Object (response from server), if it is an empty object?

Currently, my way of doing is utilising jQuery.

```
  this.http.post(url, data, {headers: headers}).then(
    result =>
     {
       if (!$.isEmptyObject(result)) {
        -- run code here --
       }else{
        -- log warning --
       }
     }
```

I dun think this is orthodox and would like to find a method that uses typescript only.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's jquery's 2.1 implementation which should also work in TypeScript:

```
isEmptyObject: function( obj ) {
    var name;
    for ( name in obj ) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
},
```

As you can see, it just tests to see if there are any enumerable properties.  You could also do `Object.keys(obj).length === 0`.